# Python subprocess always waits for programm

Tags: python, subprocess

I've got a question regarding the module "subprocess".

I programmed a Python-Script which calls a C-Programm to execute.

The Problem: The Python-Script always waits for the other programm to finish.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Good' day

Comment: Please paste the code you are using to call the external program. If your Python program needs the output of the C program to continue, it will block.

Comment: how does you code look like ? did you try `subprocess.call(command, shell=True)` ?